# Pointer Cursor on a specific part of an image html css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Now it is possible to click on the topleft corner of the image then it is changing.
What I want to do is that when the mouse comes over that specific part of the image the pointer cursor will be active. How can I fix this?

```js
let col = document.querySelectorAll('img#lights-on,img#lights-off');

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (
      e.target instanceof HTMLImageElement &&
      e.offsetX >= 0 &&
      e.offsetX <= 100 &&
      e.offsetY >= 0 &&
      e.offsetY <= 20) {
      
        col.forEach(img => {
          if (img && img.nodeType == 1) {
            img.style.display =
              ( img.style.display == '' || img.style.display == 'block' ) ?
                'none' : 'block';
          }
        })
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img
  id="lights-off"
  src="//www.collinsdictionary.com/images/thumb/apple_158989157_250.jpg" 
  style="display: none;">
<img
  id="lights-on"
  src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Banana-Single.jpg/680px-Banana-Single.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you can add a `mousemove event` to the document like you did with the `click event` but add an `else` statement to remove the cursor if it's not in the place you want:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if(
        e.target instanceof HTMLImageElement &&
        e.offsetX >= 0 &&
        e.offsetX <= 100 &&
        e.offsetY >= 0 &&
        
    ){
        document.body.style.cursor = "pointer"
    }
    else{
        document.body.style.cursor = ""
    }
})
```